# What does "Business Casual" dress code mean?

Tags: professionalism

The new company I am going to join has stated that their dress code is "Business Casual"

What does that mean?

(Some example for men please?)

#### Update

Dutch firm

Comment: You might find this varies from country to country, so you might want to add a country tag

Comment: [Also, relevant link](http://www.wikihow.com/Dress-Business-Casual)

Comment: It is a great question you should ask them.

Comment: Check out some fashion webshops. But mostly a pair of jeans (not ripped ones) with a button-up shirt tucked into your jeans will do. Chino's are good too, pantalon is mostly overkill when considering "casual". Get some nice shoes/boots (i.e. chelsea boots) as well and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 9):

> "Business Casual" What does that mean?

I agree with Kilisi, it is a step down from wearing a suit. It means that you should always be impeccable but a little less formal than the regular business attire.

My company has a business casual dress code policy where womens wear dresses, dark trousers and tops and mens wear a shirt and trousers.

When a colleague wears a pair of shorts or jeans, a T-shirt, sandals, tennis shoes or else he usually gets remarks on his/her style.

> Some example for men
>   [image]

Comment: Jeans are probably a no-no unless it is specified. But otherwise Business casual usually means khakis, polo shirt or button shirt, and a dress shoe. The HR department should provide examples of what is allowed at their workplace. Women probably have more options than men.

Comment: As a Dutch citizen, what is shown here as "casual" could pass as "business casual" for me. When I hear this term thrown around, to me it only means to not wear shorts and/or clothes related to any kind of sub-culture that may turn heads.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter I guess it all depends where you live. I work in Paris so perhaps it is a bit different than what you have in Holland. However to me what is shown as casual here would never be accepted in the company. The casual shown here doesn't show like you are doing any effort, it is more an every day look for outside of the company.

Answer (score 3):

Most places I have worked this meant trousers and a shirt, and a sports jacket at least in colder countries (basically a step down from wearing a suit). In my current country it would be a shirt and specific belted sarong type garment (basically a skirt with pockets) and sandals. So it depends where you are.